# How to customize the passed test message in a dynamic way

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I might be guilty of using pytest in a way I'm not supposed to, but let's say I want to generate and display some short message on successful test completion. Like I'm developing a compression algorithm, and instead of "PASSED" I'd like to see "SQUEEZED BY 65.43%" or something like that. Is this even possible? Where should I start with the customization, or maybe there's a plugin I might use?

I've stumbled upon [pytest-custom-report](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-custom-report), but it provides only static messages, that are set up before tests run. That's not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I might be guilty of using pytest in a way I'm not supposed to

Not at all - this is exactly the kind of use cases the [`pytest` plugin system](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/writing_plugins.html) is supposed to solve.

To answer your actual question: it's not clear where the percentage value comes from. Assuming it is returned by a function `squeeze()`, I would first store the percentage in the test, for example using the [`record_property`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.junitxml.record_property) fixture:

```
from mylib import squeeze

def test_spam(record_property):
    value = squeeze()
    record_property('x', value)
    ...
```

To display the stored percentage value, add a custom [`pytest_report_teststatus`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_report_teststatus) hookimpl in a `conftest.py` in your project or tests root directory:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    if report.when == 'call' and report.passed:
        percentage = dict(report.user_properties).get('x', float("nan"))
        short_outcome = f'{percentage * 100}%'
        long_outcome = f'SQUEEZED BY {percentage * 100}%'
        return report.outcome, short_outcome, long_outcome
```

Now running `test_spam` in default output mode yields

```
test_spam.py 10.0%                                                                  [100%]
```

Running in the verbose mode

```
test_spam.py::test_spam SQUEEZED BY 10.0%                                           [100%]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @hoefling, it worked like a charm! Turned out much easier than I thought.

Comment: @jock-tanner sure thing, happy to help!